# Get properties from SharePoint's web part settings

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

How can I access the value of a properties in a web part? I want to retrieve the "Category" field value and later be able to filter the content of my app according to what the users have the category set to. So far I have only found info on how to add the custom setting but haven't figured it out on how to retrieve it using C#.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webpart properties are nothing but attributes of a Class here is a sample of a string property
`

```
private string customProperty;
[WebBrowsable(true),
Category("Custom Properties"),
WebDisplayName("CustomProperty"),
WebDescription("CustomProperty Description"),
Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared)]
public string CustomProperty
{
    get { return customProperty; }
    set { customProperty = value; }
}
```

here you can access the property by using `this.CustomProperty`

In your scenario it will be an Enum which will result in a drop down, there also you can use the same way `this.{Your Property Name}` to access it.